# ARC: EXC_BAD_ACCESS when calling a method from inside a block, inside a delegate method

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, exc-bad-access

I created a block, inside a delegate method and I am using it to call a static method in another class. I am getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error even when I have NSZombies enabled. There are a few posts on here about similar problems - I think this one is the closest:

[ARC: Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS from inside block used in delegate method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404653/arc-getting-exc-bad-access-from-inside-block-used-in-delegate-method)

But, I haven't found anything so far that has helped. Here is the code:

```
@interface MyClass()
@property (nonatomic, copy) CaseBlock c;
@end

....

//NSURLConnection delegate method
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{        
    NSDictionary *d = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       //blows up after executing this
                       ^() { [AnotherClass staticMethod]; },authURL,
                       ^() { NSLog(@"TODO");}, searchURL,
                       ^() { NSLog(@"TODO"); }, itemURL,
                       nil];
    self.c = [[d objectForKey:[self.url path]] copy];

    if (self.c) {
        self.c();
    } else { NSLog(@"WARN unexpected response path"); }

}
```

This is the first time that I have tried to use blocks, but I can tell that this is causing the problem because calling the method from outside the block works fine. And also, as far as I can tell, all of the code that I wrote actually gets executed AND THEN the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error happens. But, I am new to Objective-C so, please correct me if I am wrong about that.

Comment: I made a more stripped down version of your example code and wasn't getting the crash. You're saying it crashes when instantiating the dictionary?

Comment: Not exactly super familiar with blocks, but my guess is that blocks aren't objects (just like an int) so you can't treat it as an object and thus you can't put it into a dictionary.

Comment: @TheAmateurProgrammer Block can be treated as objects (`id`). As far as I know they responds only to one selector `copy`. And can be safely stored in collections if you copy them from memory stack.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to copy blocks if they need to outlive the scope they were created in. Since `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:` deals with objects in general and not specifically blocks, it doesn't know to copy them, so you must copy them before passing them to it.

```
NSDictionary *d = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                   //blows up after executing this
                   [^() { [AnotherClass staticMethod]; } copy], authURL,
                   [^() { NSLog(@"TODO");} copy], searchURL,
                   [^() { NSLog(@"TODO"); } copy], itemURL,
                   nil];
```

Comment: Oh! Yes, I thought that this was the issue, but I also thought that this copy handled it: self.c = [[d objectForKey:[self.url path]] copy]; Thanks - it works now.

Comment: @CarolineM: a stack block is only valid within the scope where it was declared (in this case, it's used as an argument to a method call, so its scope is that method call). You need to copy it before it becomes invalid, and since that method doesn't copy it for you, you must copy it before passing the block to the method