# Why I got EXC_BAD_ACCESS_EXCEPTION (code= EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN) when use blocks with ARC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'm writing an application where I need to send `PNG` and `JPG` images to the server. Code for  transforming JPEG/PNG image to Base64 string I wrote as Obj-C block. But when I tried to add string returned by block to `NSDictionary` I got `code=EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN`. In my project I use ARC. I read several posts on this problem
[ARC: EXC_BAD_ACCESS when calling a method from inside a block, inside a delegate method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744378/arc-exc-bad-access-when-calling-a-method-from-inside-a-block-inside-a-delegate/) So I use `copy`! But It didn't help me.Before I use `copy` I got `EXC_BAD_EXCEPTION` with code=1 and now with code on the title.
Here is my code:

```
  __block NSUInteger image_size;

//Obj-C block where PNG or JPEG image converts to Base64 string

   NSString* (^ToBase64)(UIImage* imageToConvert, NSMutableDictionary* metadata) =

     ^(UIImage* imageToConvert, NSMutableDictionary* metadata)
{
    NSMutableData *rawData = [NSMutableData data];
    NSString* encodedImage ;
    if ([(NSString*)[metadata objectForKey:@"extension"] isEqualToString:@"PNG"])
    {
        [rawData setData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToConvert)];
        [Base64 initialize];
        encodedImage = [Base64 encode:rawData];
        image_size = [rawData length];

    }
    else if ([(NSString*)[metadata objectForKey:@"extension"] isEqualToString:@"JPG"])
    {
        [rawData setData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToConvert, 1.0)];
        [Base64 initialize];
        encodedImage = [Base64 encode:rawData];
        image_size = [rawData length];
    }
    return encodedImage;
} ;

//Initialize dictionary with image data and metadata to send
int iteration = 0;
for (UIImage* currentEntry in imagesToSent)
{ 
    NSMutableDictionary* currentImageMetadata = (NSMutableDictionary*)[imagesMetadata objectAtIndex:iteration];

   [uploadMessage setObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:

   [ToBase64(currentEntry,currentImageMetadata) copy],@"image_data",  //here I got an exception
   [currentImageMetadata objectForKey:@"extension"], @"extension",
                              [currentImageMetadata objectForKey:@"image_name" ], @"image_name", image_size, @"size", nil]

   forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d",iteration]];
     iteration++;
}
```

Comment: Is this all literally in one method? So the block is created locally right before you call it? Or have you copy/pasted code from different methods? Also, keep in mind `image_size` needs to be boxed in an NSNumber before you add it to the dictionary. With a new compiler, you can do this with `@(image_size)`.

Comment: @FirozeLafeer: That looks like the answer to the problem!

Comment: @FirozeLafeer has the right answer

Comment: Yes this all is literally one method. I create block and after that I call it from `NSDictionary` `setObject` method. Can you please explain me why I need to box `image_size` to NSNumber when `image_size` is already a `NSUInteger`?

Comment: @HarryCater, I can. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSDictionary expects its keys and values to be pointers to Objective-C objects. What you have in `image_size` is an NSUInteger, which is a primitive type (unsigned long).

So in order to store a value of a primitive type in an NSDictionary you have to wrap it in an NSNumber or NSValue. With newer versions of LLVM, that's an easy expression:

`@(image_size) // this will give you an NSNumber *`

Or if you have an older compiler then something like this:

`[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:image_size]`

By the way, I'm not sure about the use of a block in this case. It seems the motivation was to have a __block variable as the equivalent of an out parameter and nothing more? You might consider just making that a separate function or method which takes a `NSUInteger *` as an out parameter. Not the immediate issue here, but something to consider to clean this up a bit.

Comment: Tnanks man! Great answer. You really helped me.
Could you please give me a reference where I can read more about new boxing syntax: @(image_size).I didn't hear about it.

Comment: @HarryCater, here's the doc on boxed expressions and other related changes: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to be completely sure, but what you should try doing is localizing all of your variables.  Sometimes ARC doesn't reference count for one variable if you are using the same variable in multiple methods.  I had a problem similar to this once and I localized all the variables and it stopped the EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  Hope I helped.

Comment: What are you talking about?  The ObjC runtime manges everything that can be sent a retain and release, and isn't `__unsafe_unretained`.  ARC doesn't "forget to manage" anything reasonably defined.  The fact that a variable's lifetime was unexpected is your own fault.